# Magento Varien_Data_Collection returns wrong size after removing items

Tags: magento-1.4

I'm running on Magento 1.4, but also have verified the problem in 1.7.

Working with an instance of `Varien_Data_Collection` provides the use of `Varien_Data_Collection::removeItemByKey`. In my case, I'm removing items from the collection, and later trying to get the updated size of that collection, like so:

```
$body=$this->getTable()->getBody();

echo $body->getHeight(); // Outputs 25

$body->deleteRow(1);

echo $body->getHeight(); // Still outputs 25

...

My_Model_Body_Class extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

  /* @var $_rows Varien_Data_Collection */
  protected $_rows;

  public function deleteRow($index) {
    $this->_rows->removeItemByKey($index);

    return $this;
  }

  public function getHeight() {
    return $this->_rows->getSize();
  }

}

...
```

Code limited for brevity.

So if you call my `deleteRow` method, the item will in fact be removed from the collection, but subsequent calls to get the size of that collection will always return the original count. **Therefore, if I have 25 items in the collection, and remove 1, then a call to `getSize` on the collection returns 25**.

I traced this back to the parent class, in `Varien_Data_Collection::getSize`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection all items count
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSize()
{
    $this->load();
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

We see that the count hinges on the NULL status of the `_totalRecords` property. So it looks like a bug in core code. Am I reading this correctly? Should I just rely on a call to `count` on the items?

Comment: There is **no** `_rows` property in `Varien_Data_Collection` in standard Magento. Magento uses an `_items` property. And you're not using `$this->removeItemByKey()`, but `$this->_rows->removeItemByKey()`. So where does that `_rows` property come from, what kind of data does it contain, etc.?

Comment: @JürgenThelen, sorry about that. I had incorrectly summarized my code above. The instance of Varien_Data_Collection is the body model's property, `_rows`. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We see that the count hinges on the NULL status of the `_totalRecords`
>   property. So it looks like a bug in core code. Am I reading this
>   correctly?

Whether to interpret said behaviour as bug or feature, lies in the eyes of the beholder.

This behaviour is not 1.4 specific, btw; it works the same way up to the current CE version (1.8.1).

```
public function getSize()
{
    $this->load();
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

Most people for sure expect a method named `getSize()` to always return the current size, so they may call it a bug, perhaps.

But if you take a closer look at the `Varien_Data_Collection` class, you'll notice, that `getSize()` is not the only method that looks somewhat.. "weird".

Take the `addItem()` and `removeItemByKey()` methods, for example.

Why don't they increment/decrement the `_totalRecords` property, when `getSize()` uses it?

### Lazy Loading

The reason for these "weird" behaviours is, that `Varien_Data_Collection` basically is designed for the usage of the [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) pattern. That means, it allows to delay loading of the collection, until the data is really needed.

To accomplish this, `Varien_Data_Collection` implements the [`IteratorAggregate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) and [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interfaces. Their implementation points are the `getIterator()` and `count()` methods:

```
public function getIterator()
{
    $this->load();
    return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
}

public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

As you can see, both of these methods call `load()` first.

The result of this is, that whenever you use `foreach` or the PHP function `count()` on the collection, the `load()` method automatically will be called first.

Now, for a default `Varien_Data_Collection` nothing special will happen, when `load()` is called, because `load()` only calls `loadData()` and `loadData()` only returns `$this`.

But when it comes to its heavily used child class `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`, then the call to `load()` will result in loading the collection and setting `_totalRecords` to the SQL `count` of loaded records.

For performance reasons the collection usually will be loaded once only (if it hasn't been loaded yet).

So you see, depending on which context you use `Varien_Data_Collection` in, it perfectly makes sense, why `getSize()` behaves this way.

> Should I just rely on a call to `count` on the items?

If your collection is not bound to complex or slow I/O, I'd say: **yes**.

You can simply use:

```
$n = count($this->_rows->getItems());
```

Or even this way:

```
$n = count($this->_rows->getIterator());
```

Comment: That was a really informative and easily understandable answer. Thanks for your insight. It helps to peel back another layer of Magento.

Comment: Even the same issue with Magento 2...OMG...not sure how many magento folks are aware of this

Comment: Old topic/answer, but I greatly appreciate the detail put into this answer!!